# Create Remote Git Repo On Self Hosted Server

Tags: git

So I created an empty REPO on a remote server I host.

I then used the following git commands

> 1. git remote add origin
> 2. git push origin master

I then ran a git pull and it says everything is up to date.

When I push it pushes the changes and says everything is up to date.

However when I go to look at the repo on my server there are no files. Any help?

Comment: It's [bare repo](http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to push to a repository with git, you have created a **bare respository**.

```bash
git init --bare
```

This is a special kind of repository that has no working tree. To put it simply, you cannot `checkout` a branch in a bare repository. When you list the files in the remote you probably see something like

> HEAD
>   config
>   description
>   hooks
>   info
>   objects
>   refs

This is how git stores all the resources that get pushed to a bare repository. However, you can still run some git commands from a bare repository. For example:

```bash
git log master
# Will show the log of the master branch you pushed
```